# Unable to create audio compressor filter

Tags: matlab, audio, compression, video-processing

Function takes as input a string, the name of the video. It's read the video with the `vision.VideoFileReader` function and returns the same video, using the`vision.VideoFileWriter` function. Both the input video that the output videos have audio. Processing of a video about 6 MB, i have the output of a video more than 1 GB. The function has no errors, but i have to compress. Using the `VideoCompressor`, can compress the video up to 350 MB, i would use the`AudioCompressor`, but by obtaining an error.
This is my code, the following is the error returned.

```
function [ nFrames ] = showMovie( video )
v = VideoReader(video);
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader(video);
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter('FrameRate',v.FrameRate,'AudioInputPort',1,'VideoCompressor', 'MJPEG Compressor','AudioCompressor','MJPEG Compressor');

[audio,fs] = audioread(video);
op=floor(fs/v.FrameRate);

nFrames = 0;

while ~isDone(videoFReader)
    nFrames=nFrames+1;
    frame=step(videoFReader);
    audios=audio( (nFrames-1)*op + 1 : nFrames*op , : );
    step(videoFWriter,frame,audios);
end

release(videoFReader);
release(videoFWriter);
end
```

I can't use the property `AudioCompressor`. I tried both the `Compressor MJPEG` and the `DV Video Encoder` value, but I get this error:

```
Error using VideoFileWriter / step
Unable to create audio compressor filter

Error in showMovie (line 15)

step (videoFWriter, frame, audios);
```

Comment: You're trying to specify a *video* compressor for your audio. You need to use a valid *audio* compressor. You can use tab completion `videoWriter.AudioCompressor = '<tab` to get a list of available compressors on your system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only AudioCompressor compressor that works in my system is: 'None (uncompressed)'
I tried it on 64 bit version of Matlab (R2014b).
The reason for that is that my Windows system lacks x64 (64 bit) audio codec supported by Matlab.
Note: **64 bit Matlab requires x64 codecs, and 32 bit Matlab requires x86 codecs.**

When I use `videoWriter.AudioCompressor = ' % <tab> key` as **Suever** mentioned,

[image]

When I tried the same code using 32 bit version of Matlab (R2013b), I got the following list:

- AC-3 ACM Codec
- AC-3 ACM Extensible
- CCITT A-Law
- CCITT U-Law
- GSM 6.10
- IMA ADPCM
- Microsoft ADPCM
- None (uncompressed)

Note: The video codecs shown in 64 bit version, are not displayed in the 32 bit Matlab.
I guess displaying video codecs in `AudioCompressor` is a Matlab bug.

Just for the record, I tried the `<tab> key` before Suever posed his answer.
I read about it in Matlab documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilewriter-class.html

> To launch the tab completion functionality, type the following up to the open quote.
>
> y.VideoCompressor='
>
> A list of compressors available on your system will appear after you press the Tab key

The following code sample works in system:

```
video = 'xylophone.mpg';

v = VideoReader(video);
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader(video);
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter('FrameRate',v.FrameRate,'AudioInputPort',1,'VideoCompressor', 'MJPEG Compressor','AudioCompressor', 'None (uncompressed)');

[audio,fs] = audioread(video);
op=floor(fs/v.FrameRate);

nFrames = 0;

while ~isDone(videoFReader)
    nFrames=nFrames+1;
    frame=step(videoFReader);
    audios=audio( (nFrames-1)*op + 1 : min(nFrames*op, length(audio)) , : );
    
    %Handle last audio sample.
    if (length(audios) < op)
        audios = [audios; audios(1:op - length(audios), :)];
    end
    
    step(videoFWriter,frame,audios);
end

release(videoFReader);
release(videoFWriter);
```

**I was searching the Web for free x64 audio codec that works with Matlab, but I couldn't find one.**

Comment: How is this answer any different than the answer that I provided? This is really better suited as a comment on my answer.

Comment: At least my answer works... I think you didn't pay enough attention before answering.  The main issue here, is that Matlab shows both Audio and Video codecs while using the "tab trick", and there is no Audio codec available. I was testing my code sample, while you posted you answer... why not posting mine?

Comment: It still doesn't provide a solution. He doesn't want no compression.

Comment: So lets find out how to install an audio codec that works with Matlab...

Comment: Help yourself and post an answer.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for the answers. When i use `videoWriter.Audio compressor = '% <tab> key` opens the following menu, same as you.        I need to install an audio codec and use it in matlab? What can i install ?

Comment: @BernardoMarino I was searching and searching but couldn't find x64 codec. The only solution I can give you is: Use 32 bit version of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to specify a *video* compressor for your audio which is resulting in the error. Different compression algorithms are used for the audio and video components. You need to specify a valid *audio* compressor.

To get a list of available options on your machine, you can use tab completion in the command window:

```
videoWriter.AudioCompressor = ' % <tab> key
```

As Rotem has noted, this list can *also* include Video compression algorithms, but it should also include any valid audio compression algorithms for which you have the correct codecs installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. When i use `videoWriter.Audio compressor = '% <tab> key` opens the following menu, same as Rotem.     I need to install an audio codec and use it in matlab? What can i install ?